# Schur functor for coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For the Grassmannians Kapranov proved that there is a tilting bundle consisting of $\sum^{\lambda}(\mathcal{T})$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the tautological bundle and $\sum^{\lambda}$ the Schur functor. I want to learn somthing more on Schur functors, especially for sheaves. Does anybody know a good reference ?

Comment: Fulton-Harris *Representation Theory* is excellent. Once you understand it for vector spaces, it is just trivial to extend it to vector bundles.